# How can I "unhide" this form without triggering the _load event?

Tags: vb.net, forms, hide, onload-event

I'll just get straight to it, I have this code:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    startup.Show()
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

This is going to be the form which loads first, having the entire project shutting down when this form closes (hence why I have to load this form first & calling the startup from this)

After the startup form has finished it's code, I have this code:

```
    ...
    frmMain.ShowInTaskbar = True
    frmMain.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Me.Close()
```

How can I get the main form to load again without actually triggering it's _load event (thus avoiding it to trigger an infinite loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean show the main form?

```
frmMain.Show()
frmMain.BringToFront()
```

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot, I used it at first but for some reason it didn't work, that reason being it was being called through .Show too soon after being hidden thus not actually being called again

Answer (score 1):

Try this in order to show the hidden form:

```
frmMain.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a better way to tackle this is to show the startup form from the application startup event. Your main form can then *be* a main form instead of being hidden.

Comment: That's what I did at first, but the problem is I can't specifically say the entire application should close when the main form is closed, it only gives me the option to close the app when either the startup form is closed, or when all forms are closed.

Comment: In Winforms (WPF is a bit different) you can show a form from the application startup event without it being designated the Main Form, before the Main form is shown; so you can have your app close when the Main form is closed rather than when the startup form closes.  To get to the Application startup event, go to the application properties, Application tab, View Application Events button.

Comment: I see, although I'm using the normal windows forms, I personally don't really like using WPF, mainly because I'm just too used to using normal windows forms & it just seems to foreign to me with the extra code.

Comment: Well there you go then. You can put all your initialisation code in the startup event, including showing forms. The form designated as your Main Form will not show until all that code completes and the applicationstartup event returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
    startup.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Call startup.Show()
    Call startup.BringToFront()
    Call startup.Activate()
```

The essential step to unhide from windowstate minimized, which is the windowstate of hidden forms, is to change the windowstate to normal. An example of this is shown in my first line of code. The other lines are for showing, bringing to the front and activating the formerly hidden form with the name startup. Goodluck!